# Use os module in python code that has to be packaged for pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pypi

I have a python script that needs to take a directory as input and list its content.I want this script to be deployed as a PyPi package.

Since I am using the os module while installing my custom package,
pip tries to install os package as a requirement and gives an error.(obviously, because it is not pip package), how can I avoid this?

Comment: do you have a  `setup.py` or `requirements.txt` file? could you make sure that `os` is not present there

Comment: Yes the files are present and os is not there.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `pip install <yourpackage>`?